# How to make a vertical nav bar take up 100% of the height of a page?

Tags: html, css, nav

First, yes this has been asked before, but the answer is not working for me. (100vh was previously listed.)

What I'm trying to do is extend the vertical navbar all the way to the bottom of the page. Below is code I have tried but no luck in getting this to extend all the way.

The first bit of code, .rectangle, is an attempt to draw a rectangular box all the way down the page. I run into the same problem with the rectangle as I do with the vertical navbar. It doesn't make it to the bottom.

The .navContainer and .verticalNavBar are the code I basically started out with before trying the rectangular box.

Can someone help me figure out where the problem is?

Here is the code from the HTML and CSS file:

```css
}

.navContainer {

    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    background-color: grey;
}

.verticalNavBar {

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: grey;
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
    .liVerNavBar a {

    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
  <body>
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
        <nav class="navContainer">
            <ul class="verticalNavBar">
                <li class="liVerNavBar"><a href="Final_HomePage.html"><h2>Home</h2></a></li>
                <li class="liVerNavBar"><a class="active" href="Final_Resources.html"><h2>Resources</h2></a></li>
                <li class="liVerNavBar"><a href="Final_Medications.html"><h2>Medications</h2></a></li>
                <li class="liVerNavBar"><a href="Final_RequestMoreInfo.html"><h2>Request More Information</h2></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Here is what it looks like with the code given above:
[Vertical navbar stops short of bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5xdE.png)

Changing the .verticalNavBar to have the min-height: 100vh;

```css
.verticleNavBar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: grey;
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

has no affect. When I update the .navContainer so it also has the min-height: 100vh;

```css
.navContainer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    background-color: grey;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

the grey box around the navbar gets wider... taking up nearly the width of the screen.

[Navbar taking up the width of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1G95.png)

Thank you for the answers below, but unfortunately they did not effect the navbar.

Comment: add a snippet or a fiddle and why doesnt the 100vh work? what is missing?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a code snippet ? because with the code you shared the navbar is 100% of screen height. https://jsfiddle.net/352xhwmd/2/ Or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

You cann often see at the top of a stylesheet this sort of setting:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This makes sure that every element does NOT have any default padding or margin put on by the browser.

What you are probably experiencing is a gap at the bottom which is there by default.